# Can Route 53 turn on an EC2 instance if the health check fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have EVERYTHING I need for a specific goal I have in mind.

Simply put, I want to have route53 do a regular health check on a URL that I provide. If the health check fails for more than 3-4 minutes, I want it to spin up an EC2 instance with a launch configuration I have provided. After the health check comes back up for longer than 10 minutes, it can shut down the EC2 instance it created earlier.

I hope this is easily accomplished?

Comment: Side-question: Why do you want to turn on an instance if a URL fails? Will it take the load? Wouldn't you also need a mechanism to divert the traffic to the new EC2 instance? Do you want to Launch an instance, or Start/Stop the instance? Can your system really handle a potential 5-minute outage (detection + launch)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Becuase the service running on that server is not reachable with aws, so having a simple html page that's reachable can achieve the same result in the route53 health check.

The server that would spin up would in fact take the load yes, I am using SRV records to divert traffic to the(hopefully) created ec2 instance. 

it would be launching a pre-built AMI once its in an alarm state.

Yes, it's a gaming group and its a VOIP server, so this is simply a 'backup' of our primary voice server.  I don't want it running all the time to be economical.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Route 53 provides a `HealthCheckStatus` metric to Amazon CloudWatch. You could use this to trigger an Alarm when there is a failure. This can send a message to Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS), that can the trigger an AWS Lambda function.

```
Route 53 -> CloudWatch -> SNS -> Lambda
```

See: [Monitoring Health Check Status and Getting Notifications - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-monitor-view-status.html)

The **Lambda function** can do whatever you wish, including launching/terminating an instance or simply starting/stopping an instance.

If your intention is to divert traffic to an alternate service when the main service has failed, you can configure Route 53 with Primary/Secondary destinations in a **Failover configuration**. However, this is traditionally done with 'live' services (without having to turn things on & off) to provide the fastest possible failover.

Comment: Hey John,

Thanks for your reply! Do you have any idea what that lambda functions setup would look like? I think that's where i'm stuck, as I already have a health check for the route53 SVR record (which I am using in a failover config)

Comment: The content of the Lambda function is up to you. Personally, I use Python and the boto3 SDK. You might need two alarms -- one when it fails and another when it goes good. If you need help, just do a web search for things like [Launching EC2 Instances from Lambda – tomincode – Medium](https://medium.com/tomincode/launching-ec2-instances-from-lambda-4a96f1264afb).